# Is it possible to apply a React Higher Order Component to a general div?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I have a HOC called `Selectable`. It works fine like this on my own components.

`var selectableComponent = Selectable(MyComponent)`

My question is how I can pass a regular `div` as parameter

`var selectableDiv = Selectable(React.div)`

However I'm not sure it's possible to access the div component like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div` string is [React element type](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) that will be rendered as `<div>` when used as:

```
let Comp = 'div';
...
<Comp/>
```

It should be:

```
let selectableDiv = Selectable('div').
```

Comment: yes you're right. I added a little check to Selectable to see if the given component is a string and then actually used React.createElement, but to use it directly in JSX like you suggested is even better. tnx